# How to replace all occurrences of - in a file, with _ using sed? It should not affect the text surrounding the -

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

I don't have good experience in bash

The file consists of text like,

```
"text_description-1": "Some text".
```

I want to replace the '-' with '_' only on the text to the left of the colon. The text to the right may also have '-' but that should not be replaced.

I tried the following (I use a mac),

```
sed -i '' 's/[a-zA-Z0-9_"]*-[a-zA-Z0-9"]*:/[a-zA-Z0-9_"]*_[a-zA-Z0-9"]*:/g' file.txt
```

But it replaced all the text that was matched with

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_"]*_[a-zA-Z0-9"]*:
```

I only want to replace the '-' and not all the text that matches the regex. How can I do that?

Comment: So for instance, in a line `"foo-bar:baz-bam"    : "boo"`, the replaced text should be `"foo_bar:baz-bam"   : "boo"`?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
sed -E 's/-(.*:)/_\1/' file
"text_description_1": "Some text".
```

Comment: Got this error, sed: 1: "s/-(.*?:)/_\1/": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid. Also, the file consists of many such text, and I need to replace all of them.

Comment: @sanjay, try is with `s/-(.*:)/_\1/`: `sed` doesn't have lazy modifiers. But this command will replace only one dash in a line at a time.

Comment: @markalex, that worked!! I will accept the it if you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Just answered, removed one char from my code